# Insert data to json from variable

Tags: javascript, json

I use the following code for inserting data to json:

```
categories: [
                'Tokyo',
                'Jakarta',
                'New York',
                'Seoul',
                'Manila',
                'Mumbai',
                'Sao Paulo',
                'Mexico City',
                'Dehli',
                'Osaka',
                'Cairo',
                'Kolkata',
                'Los Angeles',
                'Shanghai',
                'Moscow',
                'Beijing',
                'Buenos Aires',
                'Guangzhou',
                'Shenzhen',
                'Istanbul'
            ],
```

It works, but, i want to put this data into an array or string variable like this:

```
var data = Array('Tokyo',
                'Jakarta',
                'New York',
                'Seoul',
                'Manila',
                'Mumbai',
                'Sao Paulo',
                'Mexico City',
                'Dehli',
                'Osaka',
                'Cairo',
                'Kolkata',
                'Los Angeles',
                'Shanghai',
                'Moscow',
                'Beijing',
                'Buenos Aires',
                'Guangzhou',
                'Shenzhen',
                'Istanbul');
categories: [data],
```

But, It does not work. Can  you help me ?
Thanks.

Comment: And `categories : data` (without the `[]`) does not work?

Comment: ooops, yes that's right, thanks

Comment: Is this just that which was your error?

Comment: this code was worked: `categories: [data],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data: ['Tokyo', 'Jakarta',...]
```

is already an array which is part of an object. if you want it as separate variable just create it like this:

```
var data = ['Tokyo', 'Jakarta',...];
```

and add it to your object

```
var yourObject = {categories: data};
```

you could even do stuff like this:

```
var yourObject = {categories: new Array('Tokyo', ...)};
```

but please use the bracket notation

hint: you are creating an "object literal" not a JSON-Object. JSON is just a subset of the object literal. read more [here](http://www.json.org/js.html)

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
var data = ['Tokyo','Jakarta','New York','Seoul','Manila','Mumbai','Sao Paulo','Mexico City','Dehli','Osaka','Cairo','Kolkata','Los Angeles','Shanghai','Moscow','Beijing','Buenos Aires','Guangzhou','Shenzhen','Istanbul'];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that the first part which works is exactly what you described in the second part. So it already works.

Assigning a variable like this:

```
categories : ['firstElement', 'secondElement'];
```

makes the json-field categories containing an Array object. You can access 'firstElement' by using `categories[0]` for example.

is exactly the same like:

```
var categoties = new Array();
categories.push('firstElement');
categories.push('secondElement');
```

your second attempt does not work because you can't supply your array values in the constructor `new Array(...)`. If you instantiate it with `new Array()` you can use `.push('value')` to add Elements to the array.

Comment: I think that the OP just want to have the array initialized in another part of his code and call it in his JSON object...

Answer (score 0):

```
var categories = [];

var data = ['Tokyo',
            'Jakarta',
            'New York',
            'Seoul',
            'Manila',
            'Mumbai',
            'Sao Paulo',
            'Mexico City',
            'Dehli',
            'Osaka',
            'Cairo',
            'Kolkata',
            'Los Angeles',
            'Shanghai',
            'Moscow',
            'Beijing',
            'Buenos Aires',
            'Guangzhou',
            'Shenzhen',
            'Istanbul'];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  categories.push(data[i]);
}
```

Comment: @hereandnow78 Excuse me, but the question wasn't that clear either!